# Redirect all requests to a particular page in Wicket

Tags: java, jboss, wicket, wicket-6

I'm using Wicket 6.x and I want to implement the classic "site under maintenance" page, to which all requests should be redirected depending on a condition.

However, I don't want to write the redirect check on every page, since that would be redundant.

Is there a way I can intercept all requests, do my check, and execute the redirect if necessary, from a single place??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use IRequestCycleListener#onBeginRequest() + `requestCycle.setResponsePage(MaintainancePage.class)`.

Register your listener in MyApp#init(): `getRequestCycleListeners().add(new MaintainanceListener())`.

Here is a possible solution:

```
public class MaintainanceListener extends AbstractRequestCycleListener {

    @Override
    public void onRequestHandlerResolved(RequestCycle cycle, IRequestHandler handler) {
        super.onRequestHandlerResolved(cycle, handler);
        if (handler instanceof IPageRequestHandler && isMaintainanceMode()) {
            final Class<? extends IRequestablePage> pageClass = ((IPageRequestHandler) handler).getPageClass();
            if (MaintenancePage.class != pageClass) {
                final MySession session = MySession.get();
                if (session.getUser() != null) {
                    session.invalidateNow();
                }
                cycle.setResponsePage(MaintenancePage.class);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, although this by itself will generate a redirect loop, for obvious reasons. I had to add a check on the path to skip the redirect if the requested page was the maintenance one.
Also, this crashes my site when requesting the homepage (http://example.com/). Still have to understand why